# What is $E[W_t ^2 e^{(\mu W_t - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}t)}]$?

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, expected-value

What is the expected value:

$E[W_t ^2 e^{(\mu W_t - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}t)}]$
where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian Motion and $\mu, \sigma >0$

One possible hint is: take $d/d \mu$ twice.

I don't know how to use it, could somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $f(\mu)=Ee^{\mu  W_t-\frac {\sigma^{2}t} 2}$. Then  and $f''(\mu)=E W_t^{2}e^{\mu  W_t-\frac {\sigma^{2}t} 2}$. Recall that $Ee^{\mu W_t}=e^{\mu^{2}t/2}$.

Comment: Amazing! One minor mistake, 'recall that... expected value should be e to the mu squared times t divided by 2, not t squared, because Wt ~ N(0,t)

Comment: @JosephYang Very true. Thanks for pointing out.